# Android Java+xml Extension error- Exception thrown trying to call method shell_do on sheldo

Tags: java, android, xml, gml

has anyone had experiance in game maker studio porting to android using a java extension that involves a java file and an .xml manifest? 
Version- Game Maker: Studio, also note that to make an extension involves 3 different kinds of code, Java, XML, and GML (which is basically a combination of html and visual basic)

I have a time card app I'm making for Android, that you can punch in and out, take break, and it records that info to a text file in the app's working directory.
my problem is, How to open note pad.exe (or equivalent) to display a text to the user in Game Maker: Studio?

i have my java file, named sheldo, set up in my extension, which I named supopntxtf, and in it's properties page i only have android selected, and on the functions properties page i have the name and external name both set as shell_do, the return type set as double and i have listed argument0 and argument1 as strings.
here is the code i put in the sheldo.java file:

```
     package ${YYAndroidPackageName};


    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileReader;
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.lang.String;
    import ${YYAndroidPackageName}.R;
    import com.yoyogames.runner.RunnerJNILib;

    public class sheldo extends Activity {

        public void shell_do(String arg0, String arg1) {
            if (arg0 == "open") {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
                Uri uri = Uri.parse(arg1);
                intent.setDataAndType(uri, "text/plain");
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }

       }
```

and added the xml code to the android manifest (from right clicking on my extensions name and going to the android tab) here's the code i typed in:

```
<activity 
android:label="@string/app_name" 
android:name="${YYAndroidPackageName}" />
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

and the permissions i added to it:

```
android.permission.INTERNET
android.permission.BIND_CARRIER_SERVICE
android.permission.BIND_APP_WIDGET
android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
```

ok, now in the game it'self (now we're back to GML code language) i have an object named pointer and in it's create event i have declaired these related variables:

```
result1="open";result2="No records";result3="No records";
```

in object pointer's alarm event i have this code to activate my extension:

```
result1="open";
result2=string_insert(string(global.fname[global.empnum]),string(" "),0);
result2=string_insert(string(result2),string(global.finfo[0]),0);
result2=string_insert(string(result2),string(" Week "),0);
result2=string_insert(string(result2),string(global.fiscalw),0);
result2=string_insert(string(result2),string(" "),0);
result2=string_insert(string(result2),string(global.yrs),0);
result2=string_insert(string(result2),string(".txt"),0);// result2 to this        point builds the file name.txt
result3=string_insert("file:///",working_directory,0;
result3=string_insert(result3,string("+"),0);
result2=string_insert(string(result3),string(result2),0);// this puts the     file path together
shell_do(result1,result2); // this calls the extension



   Explanation of the variables that I used to name the file with their values being all strings:
  global.fname[global.empnum] - employee name depending on the employee number
  global.finfo[0] - the company name
  global.fiscalw - the week
  global.fiscalyr - the year
```

i compiled my game (because the manual tells me extensions wont work unless the game is finish-compiled), no problems there, but when i try to use the extension nothing happens at all, but looking back through the runner log i get this error message everytime i tried to use the extension:

Exception thrown trying to call method shell_do on sheldo

I watched a couple helpfull videos on you tube to learn more about java combined with xml:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AGzaFOpVuqs&index=13&list=PLRz47KuVF6Uos2m6ZQ5J7v9xNA-LN8m7L

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tv2iClQ3G3s&list=PLRz47KuVF6Uos2m6ZQ5J7v9xNA-LN8m7L&index=14
and downloaded Android Studio and got it to work pretty easilly, but i want to finish this project on game maker: studio because i paid alot of money for it and also dont want to re-write the entire app because it's completely different language haha but I figure I must be doing something wrong somewhere, any ideas anyone?

Comment: One more hopefully helpfull piece of info is upon compiling my app there is an error message about not being able to create the class sheldo, here is the error message:

Comment: D/yoyo    (12630): doSetup called - /data/app/com.*****.RHG_Timecard_Full-2/base.apk
I/yoyo    (12630): Attempting to initialise extension class com.*****.RHG_Timecard_Full.sheldo
I/yoyo    (12630): Exception thrown attempting to create extension class com.*****.RHG_Timecard_Full.sheldo
I/yoyo    (12630): Attempting to initialise extension class com.*****.RHG_Timecard_Full.sheldo
I/yoyo    (12630): Exception thrown attempting to create extension class com.*****.RHG_Timecard_Full.sheldo

Comment: Ok, so when i compile the app, i get the error message in the compiler window that says: Exception thrown attempting to create extension class com.*****.RHG_Timecard_Full.sheldo and if i try and use the extension with the compiled app running i get the message Exception thrown trying to call method shell_do on sheldo so why can't the compiler create the extension class? what would cause that error? any thoughts would be greatly appreciated, I'm out of ideas why this would work in android studio but not in game maker: studio's extension